# SchemaTron Date Comparison

Tags: xslt, xpath, schematron

```
<ROOTNODE>
   <Blocks>
     <Block>
    <Ref/>
      <BlockDates Start="2015-10-20" End="2015-10-25" />
      <Types>
        <Type TypeCode="SGL">
         <TypeAllocations>
        <TypeAllocation Start="2015-10-26" End="2015-10-27" />
        <TypeAllocation Start="2015-10-26" End="2015-10-25" />
      </TypeAllocations>
       </Type>
         <Type TypeCode="SGL">
         <TypeAllocations>
        <TypeAllocation Start="2015-10-28" End="2015-10-29" />
        <TypeAllocation Start="2015-10-26" End="2015-10-27" />
      </TypeAllocations>
       </Type>
      </Types>
    </Block>

    <Block>
      <Ref/>
      <BlockDates Start="2015-10-26" End="2015-10-30"/>
       <Types>
        <Type TypeCode="SG">
         <TypeAllocations>
        <TypeAllocation Start="2015-10-31" End="2015-11-01" />
        <TypeAllocation Start="2015-10-25" End="2015-10-24" />
      </TypeAllocations>
       </Type>
         <Type TypeCode="SG">
         <TypeAllocations>
        <TypeAllocation Start="2015-10-21" End="2015-10-25" />
        <TypeAllocation Start="2015-10-23" End="2015-11-27" />
      </TypeAllocations>
       </Type>
      </Types>
    </Block>
   </Blocks>
   </ROOTNODE>
```

I'm trying to find a way to tell if the <TypeAllocation @Start and @End> dates are outside the <BlockDates @Start and @End> dates. There can be any number of <TypeAllocation> elements and <Type> elements. The above should fail in all cases. Below is what I tried. However I feel that its way off as it only finds the first one. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
   <sch:pattern name="Testing Start and End dates">
                                                                                <sch:rule context="blk:InvBlock">
                                                                                    <sch:report test="translate(blk:InvBlockDates/@Start, '-', '') &lt;= translate(blk:RoomTypes/blk:RoomType/blk:RoomTypeAllocations/blk:RoomTypeAllocation/@Start, '-', '') or translate(blk:InvBlockDates/@End, '-', '') &lt;= translate(blk:RoomTypes/blk:RoomType/blk:RoomTypeAllocations/blk:RoomTypeAllocation/@End, '-', '')"> Allocation @Start and @End dates can not be outside the Block @Start and @End dates. </sch:report>
                                                                                </sch:rule>
                                                                            </sch:pattern>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Yeah I need check all the Allocation start and End dates with-in the Block. I forgot to mention I'm use Schematron 1.5 with this one. So the current() function is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you want to report an validation error if there is at least one `TypeAllocation` with the wrong `Start` or `End` or if you want to check all of them. If you only want to check that at least one of them is wrong then you can use

```
<sch:pattern>
    <sch:rule context="Block">
        <sch:report test="Types/Type/TypeAllocations/TypeAllocation[
                            translate(@Start, '-', '') > translate(current()/BlockDates/@Start, '-', '')
                            or
                            translate(@End, '-', '') > translate(current()/BlockDates/@End, '-', '')]"> Allocation @Start and @End dates can not be outside the Block @Start and @End dates. </sch:report>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```

I think. If your version of Schematron does not support the use of the `current()` function then in the context of your example respectively my suggestion you can use `ancestor::Block` instead of `current()`:

```
<sch:pattern>
    <sch:rule context="Block">
        <sch:report test="Types/Type/TypeAllocations/TypeAllocation[
                            translate(@Start, '-', '') > translate(ancestor::Block/BlockDates/@Start, '-', '')
                            or
                            translate(@End, '-', '') > translate(ancestor::Block/BlockDates/@End, '-', '')]"> Allocation @Start and @End dates can not be outside the Block @Start and @End dates. </sch:report>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using the following. Thank you so much for your help Martin!

```
<sch:rule context="Block">
    <sch:report test="Types/Type/TypeAllocations/TypeAllocation[
    translate(@Start, '-', '') &lt; translate(ancestor::Block/BlockDates/@Start, '-', '') ]
    or
    Types/Type/TypeAllocations/TypeAllocation[translate(@End, '-', '') &gt; translate(ancestor::Block/BlockDates/@End, '-', '')] ">
    Allocation @Start and @End dates can not be outside the Block @Start and @End dates.
    </sch:report>
</sch:rule>
```